# swift cant get beacon

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, beacon

Have a project from 2 yrs ago that I just updated from swift 3 to 4. No real significant changes other than the plist getting new permissions. Ran the app on a real device and the beacon isn't being found. UUID, major and minor all verified numerous times to be valid and correct. BKON beacon is sitting next to phone.

plist is like so
[image]

location manager is setup like so in viewDidLoad

```
 var locationManager:CLLocationManager!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.  

    print("locationManager setup")
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.delegate = self
}
```

Region/beacon setup

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .authorizedAlways {
        if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self) {
            if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable() {
                setupBeacons()
            }
        }
    }
}
func setupBeacons(){
    print("setupBeacons")
    if let beaconUUID = UUID.init(uuidString: "58de905b-3b54-bf9d-2d01-4dc018eaf6cc") {
        let region1 = CLBeaconRegion(
            proximityUUID: beaconUUID,
            major: 998,
            minor: 1330, //2121
            identifier: "Crossing1")
        region1.notifyOnEntry = true
        region1.notifyOnExit = true
        region1.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = true
        startMonitoringBeacon(region: region1)
    }
}
func startMonitoringBeacon(region: CLBeaconRegion){
    locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
    locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region)
}
```

I then have the delegate call back set like so

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    print("didRangeBeacons: found \(beacons.count)")
}
```

But no beacons are ever found. No errors or anything in the other delegate methods (rangingBeaconsDidFailFor, monitoringDidFailFor and didFailWithError). I've already tried removing all beacons from the locationmanager, uninstalling, reinstalling the app numerous times and rebuilding the app from scratch.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: can you detect your beacon with an off the shelf detector app like LocateBeacon?  Are the identifiers what you expect?

Comment: @davidgyoung no it cannot. I took the beacon back to the owner of the beacon after finding it wasn't being found based upon the UUID given. They said they are anonymizing the UUID so they have things mixed up. Appreciate the insight into using an off the shelf detector in moving things forward.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that your beacon is not advertising the same UUID/major/minor  as your app is looking for.   You need a beacon to test with.  You can use the same app above to transmit a beacon with identifiers 58de905b-3b54-bf9d-2d01-4dc018eaf6cc 998 1130 to see if it detects it.  But you'll need two phones, one to run your app, and one to run the beacon transmitter.  If that works, then the problem is with the beacon.